# Prove $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{Z}:m=p\implies m+n=p+n$

Tags: proof-writing

My question is whether proving $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{Z}:m=p\implies m+n=p+n$ is equivalent to prove $\forall n,p\in \mathbb{Z}:p+n=p+n$ and if it is **why?**

Comment: Yes, because if we prove p+n=p+n, and we know that m=p, then p+n=m+n.

Comment: @Ilovemath The question rised because proving $p+n=p+n$ turned out to be easier for me than proving $m=p\implies m+n=p+n$ and found it funny. Is that normal (such a difficulty)?

Comment: Yes it's normal....as far as I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define the integers as equivalent classes of pairs of natural numbers.

Precisely, $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ iff there are natural numbers $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d = (m,n)$.

We say two integers $m = (m_{1},m_{2})$ and $n = (n_{1},n_{2})$ are equivalent iff $m_{1} + n_{2} = m_{2} + n_{1}$.

Moreover, we define the addition as follows:

$$m + n = (m_{1} + n_{1},n_{2} + m_{2})$$

Hence, if we assume $m = (m_{1},m_{2})\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n = (n_{1},n_{2})\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p = (p_{1},p_{2})\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $m = p$, we get
\begin{align*}
m + n & = (m_{1} + n_{1}, m_{2} + n_{2})\\\\
& = (m_{1} + n_{1} + p_{2}, m_{2} + n_{2} + p_{2})\\\\
& = (m_{2} + n_{1} + p_{1}, m_{2} + n_{2} + p_{2})\\\\
& = (n_{1} + p_{1},n_{2} + p_{2})\\\\
& = p + n
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!